# Passing variable name in a function

Tags: r, function, variables

I am trying to pass the value of the variable in the function and use it in a simple formula but not able to. It gives me following error

Error in data$column_namep : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Here is the code:

```
test = function(func,data="file3",column_name,x=1){
  func(data$column_name[x])
}

test(sum,column_name = "chemical")
```

expected result it i get sum of the column_name "chemical"

Comment: try: `data[[column_name]][x]`

Comment: Error in data[[column_name]] : subscript out of bounds .  I get this error

Comment: I see.. try instead of data `get(data)`.

Comment: This would be solved very fast if you had provided a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Not that this makes much sense to sum over one element, here is a code that runs without errors:

```
test = function(func,data="file3",column_name,x=1){
  func(get(data)[[column_name]][x])
}

file3 <- iris
test(func = sum, column_name = "Sepal.Length")
[1] 5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get sum by column_name. You can access column data using index (no need to use column name, I would prefer this) or column name. The following code provides the sum over column 2 i.e. `"Sepal.Width"` for `iris` dataset.

```
test = function(func,data=iris,x){
  func(data[,x]) # Can access data using column index or name
}

test(sum,x=2) or test(sum,x="Sepal.Width")
```

Output:

```
[1] 458.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a statement that checks for numeric type:

```
 summer<-function(func,df,col.name){
  x<-df
  mynames<-names(df)
  col.name1<-which(mynames==col.name)
  x<-func(df[col.name1])
  x
  }
```

summer(sum,iris,"Sepal.Width")

```
summer(sum,iris,"Sepal.Width")
[1] 458.6
```